# Animating NSLayoutConstraint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a MainVC(`UIViewController`) with a MainTableVC(`UITableView`) and another nested SubTableVC(`UITableView`).
Both of them has the MainVC as its `delegate` and `dataSource`, also, each one has its own `restorationIdentifier` so I can distinguish between them when I call a delegate or dataSource function.

Here's an example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch tableView.restorationIdentifier {
    case "MainTableVCID":
        return 10
    case "SubTableVC":
        return 5
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

That's working perfectly great. But one issue I have here and I couldn't solve is:

I have a UIPickerView that's a subview of the MainVC's view, it's constrained just below the MainVC's view with constraints like this:

```
private let pickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    picker.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return picker
}()

private var pickerViewBottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //other init code..

    view.addSubview(pickerView)
    pickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    pickerViewBottomAnchor = pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 180)
    pickerViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true
    pickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

[image]

In the nested tableView (SubTableVC), in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` I want to animate the NSLayoutConstraint's constant to be equal to Zero.
However, at this time, I get pickerViewBottomAnchor = nil when I use console to print object (po self. pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant) `//prints nil`.

Here's the code I use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.restorationIdentifier == "SubTableVC" {
        pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 180
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post more code? From this what you've presented there is nothing what would be cause of the 'nil'. Also the picker with bottom constant = 180 going to be out of bounds. Is to that what you want ?

Comment: @yerpy Yes, I want it to be out of bounds, and when the user clicks on a cell, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I want to the bottom constant = 0. Regarding the nil situation, when I change the bottom constant in any other function inside the class itself with the main tableView, it not returns nil.

Comment: Where is the code that is creating `pickerView`? Are you setting `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: OK - if you use `pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 0`, does the picker view appear?

Comment: Yes, if I set it from the very beginning, or even changing it in viewDidApper(), the pickerView appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with changing your `didSelectRowAt` function to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant != 0 {
        pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
    } else {
        pickerViewBottomAnchor?.constant = 180
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Using that, selecting a row in *either* table should alternately slide the picker view up or down.

If that doesn't do anything, then you (likely) do not have your table views `.delegate` property set correctly.

If / when that *does* work, edit the function to only act when you've selected a row on the `subTableView`

Comment: Thanks @DonMag, I figured out that I was creating a struct to hold some constants, one of them is the MainVC, like: `let mainVCDelegate = MainVC()`, so the `SubTableVC.delegate = MyStruct.mainVCDelegate` was setting the delegate to a new instance of the MainVC. The solution was to add `MyStruct.mainVCDelegate = self` in MainVC's `viewDidLoad()`.  Thanks again.